# Jquery Tabs not working within the cycle for

Tags: jquery, for-loop, jquery-tabs

This is my code:
-script:

```
<script>

       $(function() {
       $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
       });
     </script>
```

-HTML:

```
for($i=0;$i<$num_panels;$i++)
    {
        $data0=pg_fetch_row($result0);

        $name=$data0[5];
        $label_name=$data0[6];
        $script_link=$data0[7];

        echo "<div id=\"tabs\" width=\"590px\">";
        echo "<ul><li>";
        echo "<a href=\"#tabs-\".$i> $name </a>";
        echo "</li>";
        echo "</ul>";

        echo "<div id=\"tabs-\".$i>
            <p>hnckbrg</p>
            </div> ";       
    }
        echo "</div>";
```

this code is only generating the first tab. I do not know how to solve. can you help me?

Comment: I think that's inline PHP within the HTML.

Comment: @E Wit: good call. My bad. Silliness deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I notice a problem with the generated HTML:

```
echo "<a href=\"#tabs-\".$i> $name </a>";
echo "</li>";
echo "</ul>";

echo "<div id=\"tabs-\".$i>
```

Would result in the following HTML:

```
<a href="tabs-"1>Name</a>
</li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-"1>...
```

Notice how the id's are `"tabs-"[Number]` as opposed to `"tabs-[Number]"`.
Same problem with the href. This might be it or at least part of it.

Edit:
Also looking over your code you're printing the start of the tabs multiple times.
You'll probably want to format the code a little different such as:

```
//Collect all the data.
$data = [];
for($i=0;$i<$num_panels;$i++)
{
    $data[]=pg_fetch_row($result0);
}

// Print the tab buttons
echo "<div id=\"tabs\" width=\"590px\">";
echo "<ul>";
for($i=0;$i<$num_panels;$i++) 
{
    $name=$data[$i][5];
    $label_name=$data[$i][6];
    $script_link=$data[$i][7];

    echo "<li><a href=\"#tabs-$i\"> $name </a></li>";
}

//Close the tabs
echo "</ul>";

//Output all the panels.
for($i=0;$i<$num_panels;$i++) 
{

    echo "<div id=\"tabs-$i\">
        <p>hnckbrg</p>
        </div> ";       
}
//Close #tabs
echo "</div>";
```

This code comes with a warning my PHP is a little bit rusty.

Comment: still does not work. only appears the first tab and the remaining contents of the tab.

Comment: Now there is another problem: the content of tabs appears only on the first tab.
But it appears all the tabs: D

Comment: Then please consider accepting the answer so that others know the problem is solved.